# SQL How would I show a rolling 3 month average for this query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Need some help with maths side of things with this bit of code.  You may see I need help on even more! But any help you could give me would be great

Basically, my aim is to bring back an;
- AccountID,
- something called a SPID, of which there could be multiple in an account,
- Billed Date
- The amount of the invoice on the corresponding billed date
- Then 3 Month Average

The last part is what I am having an issue with

So far I have done this

```
Select 
t3.AccountID,
t3.SPID,
t2.BilledDate,
Amount = Sum (t1.Amount)

From dbo.table1 t1
Inner Join dbo.table2 t2
On t1.item1 = t2.item2

Inner Join Table3 t3 
On t2.Item1 = t3.item3

Where AccountID In (xxxxxxx)
And t2.BilledDate >= '20190401' 

Group By 
AccountID
,t3.spid
,t2.BilledDate
,t1.Discount
```

Now this gives me the raw data as so (apologies, not sure hwo to show in here, if someone can pleas edit that would be great);

```
 AccountID  SPID    BilledDate  Amount
xxx930  xxxxx1  05/04/2019  11.81
xxx930  xxxxx2  07/05/2019  11.01
xxx930  xxxxx3  06/06/2019  11.38
xxx930  xxxxx4  04/07/2019  11.01
xxx930  xxxxx5  06/08/2019  11.38
xxx930  xxxxx6  06/09/2019  11.38
xxx930  xxxxx7  04/10/2019  11.01
xxx930  xxxxx8  06/11/2019  11.38
xxx930  xxxxx9  04/12/2019  11.01
xxx930  xxxxx10 07/01/2020  11.38
```

However I would like a column at the end which would show the average of the cost for the previous 3 months

I have tried to use lead and lag functions, but I keep getting NULL in the column, which is where I think I'm gong wrong

any advice or help would be great

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you have a month missing, or more than 1 entry for a single month? Your sample suggests no, but that doesn't mean that isn't the case.

Comment: ah, no there wouldn't be in the case as the BilledDate is when the invoice gets sent out, and there's only one invoice a month

Comment: Thank you for the edit @Zip !

Comment: Is that in answer to both questions? So there will **always** be a row?

Comment: Sorry @Larnu. Yes, there will always be a row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there will always be a row, then seems like the easiest would be with a windows `AVG` function. Using the end sample values you have:

```
SELECT V.AccountID,
       V.SPID,
       V.BilledDAte,
       V.Amount,
       AVG(V.Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY V.AccountID ORDER BY V.BilledDate
                           ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS Last3Average
FROM (VALUES('xxx930','xxxxx1 ',CONVERT(date,'05/04/2019'),11.81),
            ('xxx930','xxxxx2 ',CONVERT(date,'07/05/2019'),11.01),
            ('xxx930','xxxxx3 ',CONVERT(date,'06/06/2019'),11.38),
            ('xxx930','xxxxx4 ',CONVERT(date,'04/07/2019'),11.01),
            ('xxx930','xxxxx5 ',CONVERT(date,'06/08/2019'),11.38),
            ('xxx930','xxxxx6 ',CONVERT(date,'06/09/2019'),11.38),
            ('xxx930','xxxxx7 ',CONVERT(date,'04/10/2019'),11.01),
            ('xxx930','xxxxx8 ',CONVERT(date,'06/11/2019'),11.38),
            ('xxx930','xxxxx9 ',CONVERT(date,'04/12/2019'),11.01),
            ('xxx930','xxxxx10',CONVERT(date,'07/01/2020'),11.38))V(AccountID,SPID, BilledDate,Amount);
```

Comment: Thanks Larnu, this worked a treat and had not seen the function before.  Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I think `apply` is your best bet, because you don't seem to have one row per account and month:

```
with t as (
      <your query here>
     ) 
select t.*, tt.running_amount_3
from t outer apply
     (select avg(t2.amount) as running_amount_3
      from t t2
      where t2.AccountID = t.AccountID and
            t2.BilledDate <= t.BilledDate and
            t2.BilledDate > dateadd(month, -3, t.BilledDate)
     ) tt;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, sorry I tried Larnu's first and it brought back exactly what I wanted.  Cheers for your answer and help though!

Comment: @Wil-Liam . . . The two answers do not produce the same results.  This returns 3 months of results based on the *calendar*.   Larnu's returns three months of data based on what is in the data -- so if a month is skipped, the previous month is used.